# What does Internal Storage Free on the Settings|Apps screen mean?

Tags: settings, internal-storage

On the *Settings|Apps* screen at the bottom there is a graph showing Internal Storage and then a gigabyte number. When the screen is first loaded a **smaller number** is given then after a few seconds a **slightly higher number** and then an **even higher number**. What does the **slightly higher number** and **even higher number** represent?

Comment: Android has always done this, and still does on 4.4.4 KitKat to this day. I have no idea why it does this, but the lowest (first) figure tends to be the actual / accurate figure. Unless it then works out how big the caches are and takes that away from the storage used? I'll have a look around.